# why the label never replace the previous value to new value?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

The label is in my tableview:

```
UILabel *label1;
    label1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500,75, 50, 50)];
    label1.text=[arr_count objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [label1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    label1.tag=100;
    [cell addSubview:label1];
```

increment occurs here using button action

```
       - int tagValue=[[arrCount objectAtIndex:click.tag] intValue];
    if(tagValue <=5)
        {

        tagValue++;
            NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInt:click.tag];
            [arrCount replaceObjectAtIndex:click.tag withObject:num];
           NSLog(@"increment %@",arrCount);
        }
     NSIndexPath *ind=[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:click.tag];
    label2.text = arrCount[click.tag];
    [self.mTableView.tableView reloadInputViews];
}
```

increment the values and i stored it to an array.the array values given to the label.i am mentioned the problem as a image.

enter image description here [[image: i get output like this after i increment]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLMKD.png)

Comment: Where do you call `reloadData` on your table view?

Comment: @Vive, I am just guessing because a) it is a beginners problem, b) he is using an indexPath to access an array's data, c) he adds his UILabel to a superview named `cell` and d) he changes the content of the array and expects the UI to reflect that change. . I could be wrong, though, but I am quite positive.

Comment: `alloc` + `init` each time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called?

Comment: Don't add a label to the cell over and over. Add the label once and update that label's text.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question; you `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `no` but don't manually add a layout constraint. This is a bad thing to do. I would delete that line.

Comment: ok i will remove that @Desdenova , i willing to learn about that thats why i added i verified that bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored a bit your code, and it seems to work:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9]];
NSLog(@"original %@", array);
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    int value = [array[i] intValue];
    value += 1;

    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@(value)];
    NSLog(@"incremented %@", array);
}
```

Output:

```
original (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
incremented (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

And some notices:

1. That's highest time to switch to modern obj-c. Write
   `label1.text=[arr_count[indexPath.row];` or `arr_count[click.tag]`.
2. Your code is insecure. Your app may crash because of out of index. Before getting tagvalue (btw you should call it tagValue according to obj-c style) you should check if the array contains so many objects
3. Name thing correctly to increase readability of your code:

   - `arr_count` is a bad name, 1st in objc we don't use `_` in names, 2nd we don't use shortcuts, 3rd it suggest its a counter - number, not the array
   - `tagvalue` is also bad, each word after word 0 should have capital letter, so it should be `tagValue`.
4. Lastly, isn't it better to keep `NSNumber` instead of `NSString` with number value in your array? More formatting but it's much more correct!

So now let's fix the real bug: not only you have to swap value in the array but you must update the value of the label after swapping the value in the array - that's why it isn't working. The label.text copies the value from the array and won't update if you update your array. You need to manually update the label according to your array.

So after your code you should write:

```
label1.text = arr_count[click.tag];
```

However I strongly recommend to refactor your code to the mentioned points, to make your code better and improve your developer skills :)

Comment: Also I wonder where did you put that alloc of the label if that's in tableView? If you're using storyboards just place the label in your storyboard. If in code, you should add this in `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` method of your cell subclass (yes, you should have cell subclass to adopt MVC).

Comment: where i have to place the initWithFrame sister

Comment: @Kishorekumar You should do a subclass of your cell (like you do a subclass of `UIViewController`) and there you can overwrite `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` method. Just remember to call `super` :)